# Comuinicating with server

Tags: javascript, html, json, apache, websocket

I need to get my http Server to be able to receive Strings from a client and store them on the Server. At the moment i use a XAMPP-Apache-http(I dont know, which information is helpfull) server with a single, simple index.html on it, but if its impossible with it, I cloud also use another programm. I want to use JSON for transmiting the data, but first I need to somehow configure a socked for it.

I think this is done by having a script on the server, that sends the client a costume Socked to comunicate on. But I dont have any idea were this script would be placed, in the normal /htdos dosent make sence to me, cause then it would run on the client side (were i also need another script). I think i missunderstood some basic ideas. Also: arnt the client and server comunication on port 80? If they do, do I need to change the preset Port or just use a script or another application ...

The html:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="some_Text" name="some_Text" />

    <button type="submit" id="SEND_button" name="SEND_button" onclick="myFunction()">SEND</button>

    <script type="text/Javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var thatText = document.getElementById('some_Text').value;


            alert(thatText);


            window.location.replace("https://google.com/");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

insted of the alert(thatText) I want to send thatText to the server.

hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax and send a post request :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<< URL >>',
    data: {
        "text": thatText
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert('Done');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert('Error');
    },
});
```

Comment: Fist, thanks for your anwser. Sady i dont have enouth time to understad it, but the first problem i can see, is that i dont have any idea what ajax is and that i cannot, even with google, understand the sintax. but thanks for your answer, i will try my best to understad it :).

Comment: @ErikEverythingLUL There is many doc about Ajax : https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp

Comment: thanks, I needed some time but i got it to work: var input = $("#some_Text").val(); in the $.ajax: url: 'input.php' , data: "input=" + input, . then the input. php: 
<?php
$input=$_POST['input'];
echo $input;
?>

if someone got the same Question as i did: 
u can get the $input to ur html by adding:
success: function(result){
<<what ever u wont to do with $input or result(they are the same)>>
}

Comment: @ErikEverythingLUL Good job ... There is many ways to do that :)